# iPhone: Phonegap: Audio Playing in Background

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm using [this Code](http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap) to stream an MP3 audio file in background mode in Phonegap. But the Problem is: With this Code there is no way to get the current position and all the other phonegap functions with this Code. 
I tried the native quicktime/childbrowser method to play the file. This works great and shows timeline etc. BUT there is no way to hide the quicktime player and browse in the app and there is also no way to save the position and set the position in the audio files. Any Ideas to solve the issue?

Comment: I think you have to write a plugin for that

Comment: no way to solve that in javascript? Is it possible to get the position or go to a position with this audio object?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question, I thought you wanted to play local file, stored on the iPhone. To get the position and other info. use this properties of the `myaudio` object: `startTime`, `duration`, `currentTime`, `playbackRate`, `volume`, `seeking`. Note that streamed music like in the sample code is by default not seekable, so check the `seekable` property.

Comment: Thanks! That allready helped me a lot! But i think for such a small app is would be too much effort to build an own player. How hard would it be to show and hide the quicktime window/panel with a button in cocoa?

Comment: @Bonsai is a file within the app or a external stream? for stream, there is a plugin for that https://github.com/devgeeks/phonegap-plugins/tree/AudioStreamer/iPhone/AudioStream

Answer (score 1):

One other option (if you are not scared of code in development) is a plugin for streaming audio (including fixed length files like mp3's) for PhoneGap on iOS.

https://github.com/devgeeks/phonegap-plugins/tree/AudioStreamer/iPhone/AudioStream

It's currently in development and may have bugs, but it is fairly feature rich.

I also have an example iPhone project that uses it:

https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleAudioStreamer

If you give it a try and find any bugs let me know. I am pretty quick to squash them as I am trying to get it ready to fold in to the main PhoneGap plugins repo.

Comment: If anyone stumbles on this, I have not done anything with that plugin in aaagggeees... in the end I ended up using html5 audio for my iOS app. I made an example project showing how I did that as well: https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming

Comment: Devgeeks, does your html 5 implementation handle background audio?

Comment: Yes it does. It also correctly handles the remote controls (on the lock screen, etc).

Comment: Devgeeks, I'm about to check this out.. i wonder does it handle resuming playback (seeking) for streams (server range requests)